# Custom CSS for a Blog List

Tags: html, css, post, blogs

I am currently creating a PHP based Website which needs to list the Programmes... I tried creating a custom CSS code by myself, tried breaking templates to get the CSS. But everything failed. So could somebody help me get the CSS code for a `div` which look like the one given below

[image]

I would add the classes for buttons and other icons by myselves. I just want the `div` which is also reponsive. I am not much expert in CSS. I only want the alignment. Not the fancy elements inside it.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with your code, then possibly help could be provided.

Comment: which div do you mean?

Comment: the whole thing in the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SanthoshNelson/w5yx3stx/) please check this out, hope you can edit the fiddle based on your needs

HTML

```
<div class='customHeight'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-6 custom'>
            <div class='dateHolder'>27 Nov</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class='row '>
                <h3>Some title goes here</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row bottomGap">location / date goes here</div>
            <div class="row bottomGap">Content goes here Content goes here
                Content goes here Content goes here Content goes here Content goes
                here Content goes here Content goes here Content goes here</div>
            <div class='row'>
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    Buy Tickets
                    <button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">
                            Buy Tickets
                            <button>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
    *
```

> .bottomGap{
>           margin-bottom:5px;
>       }
>
> ```
> .custom {
>    background-color: #ccc;
>     height:200px; 
> }
> .customHeight{
>  height:200px;   
>
> }
> .dateHolder{
>     height:80px;
>     width:50px;
>     background-color:#000;
>     padding-top:10px;
>     padding-left:10px;
> }
> ```

*

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }

.c {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color:#eee;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.c:after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

.c > div {
  padding: 5px;
  height:100%;
  
}

.c > div:first-child {
  float:left;
  width: 30%;
  background-color:#aaa;
  margin:0 0 0 0;
}
.c > div:last-child {
  float:left;
  width: 70%;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```